# Navbar mobile to be colapsed when open page

Tags: css, laravel, navbar

I've been working on a nav bar... this is the code:

> ```
> <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" data-toggle="collapse" >
> ```

Toggle navigation
      
      
      
    
    Ferreteria

when i open this on a mobile device it opens expanded, but i want it shows at first contracted, so when i click it expands

Comment: What do i need to add to the options ?

Comment: Are you using jquery toggle?

Comment: yes, <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" >  Why?

Comment: Not sure without looking at your CSS but you may need `display:none` so that it is hidden until toggled.